# Visual studio 2017 (up to update 3) Hangs or slows down when working with solutions mixing .net framework and .net core projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

When we mix .net core and .net framework projects in the same solution, VS becomes very slow while working with is.

This same slowdown is also observed when we have two solutions in the same folder, one containing .net core projects and another containing .net framework solutions, and the two are opened by two concurrent instances of VS.

If the two solutions are in different folders, no slowdown is observed, even if they are opened simultaneously.

FYI, the solution contains asp.net core (both on .net core and .net framework), class libraries and console applications.

Comment: And the question is... where do you log a ticket for this?